# Can I cross the Canada-US border with an expired passport and a non-expired Nexus card?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, canadian-citizens, nexus

My passport will expire soon, but I have a Nexus Card good for a few more years.  Is it possible when my passport expires that I can use my Nexus card instead to go into the USA?  If so, will there be issues getting back into Canada?

Comment: Why don't you just renew your passport?

Comment: I would not take the chance of passing the US custom (especially) with an expired passport, even with a nexus card.

Comment: @Max A NEXUS is fully valid on it's own

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Why should they? Completely unnecessary

Comment: @Coke Why wouldn't they? Unless they want to limit their world to Canada and US only.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Well we're talking about trips between Canada and the US now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  I use NEXUS (and have a Canadian passport).  I renewed my passport a few months ago.  I asked border agents from both US and Canadian customs if I was okay during the renewal process, and they advised that I was still allowed to use NEXUS.  You may have issues flying, as airlines might insist on you having a valid passport, but land crossings are certainly not a problem.

My next crossing was done under exactly these circumstances and everything went fine.

Comment: "You may have issues flying, as airlines might insist on you having a valid passport" They're not supposed to, because their database, Timatic, clearly says a NEXUS card on its own is valid. Nowadays you don't even need to be flying from a pre-clearance airport.

Comment: @Coke I've no personal experience trying that - next time I have a transborder flight I'll test it out!

Comment: If they try denying you boarding, ask them to check Timatic. It says the following, when Canada is put as the nationality and the US as the Destination: "Passport Exemptions: Nationals of Canada with a NEXUS Card embarking in Canada or USA." and "Nationals of Canada with a NEXUS Card embarking in Canada in
  a non-USCBP pre-cleared flight must clear US immigration via
  the normal inspection lines. The use of Global Entry kiosk
  is not possible.". Whether this also excludes you from using APC (a different set of kiosks) I do not know

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a passport at all.

A NEXUS card alone is valid for entry to the US and Canada, even by air if flying between the US and Canada. Same goes for a Canadian enhanced driving licence (by land)

So just show your NEXUS Card.